# Why is it allowed to access a private field of another object?

Tags: java, private

Recently, I observed an unexpected behavior of accessing priavte fields in Java. Consider the following example, which illustrates the behavior:

```
public class A {

    private int i;  <-- private field!

    public A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void foo(A a) {
        System.out.println(this.i);  // 1. Accessing the own private field: good
        System.out.println(a.i);     // 2. Accessing private field of another object!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new A(5)).foo(new A(2));
    }
}
```

Why I am allowed to access the private field of another object of class `A` within the `foo` method (2nd case)?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Private fields protect a class, not an instance. The main purpose is to allow a class to be implemented independently of its API. Isolating instances between themselves, or protecting the instance's code from the static code of the same class would bring nothing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik No. In practice I even observed that people prefer to upvote when they see the picture of a user. A CW answer gather less upvotes and less acceptations (I can't say for sure for downvotes). If you think it's bad, you can fix it, though.

Comment: @dystroy I definitely have no reason to think it's bad, just very unusual. How do you decide when to make it a CW answer? The whole feature is there mainly as a measure against exploits like constantly making small edits to your answer to bring it to the top of the Recently Active list, in the hope to garner more attention=>upvotes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, When, on an easy question, I feel I'll be upvoted and/or accepted mostly because I was the first to answer among experienced coders, I often mark my answer as CW. This also makes it easier for other users to improve it. I don't make it a rule nor pretend other users should do the same, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is because they are of the same class. This is allowed in Java.

You will need this access for many purposes. For example, in an implementation of equals:

```
public class A {
  private int i;

  @override public boolean equals(Object obj){
     if(obj instanceof A){
        A a = (A) obj;
        return a.i == this.i; // Accessing the private field
     }else{
       return false
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily _need_ it, but it makes it a little less verbose to access it.

Comment: @NoobUnChained: Do all your private fields have public accessors? What is the point of encapsulation if it is so?

Answer (score 0):

The foo method belongs to the same class as does the variable i  there is no harm in allowing such an access.